# SAML response digest?

Tags: saml

I am new to SAML. I want to know **how to secure the SAML request and response communication** between Service Provider and Identity Provider? I have seen an element digest in SAML response message examples. Can that be helpful to solve my doubt. How is that implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you creating or validating signatures? Here are the (really) basic steps --

- canonicalization of XML
- create digest value, typically SHA1 (but could be SHA256 amongst others)
- base64 encode it

SAML requires the XML Signature Syntax and Processing specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) for signed messages. If you don't do this properly, you will have interop issues with other 3rd Party partners since they won't be able to validate your signed messages (resulting in invalid messages) or you will not be able to validate their messages.

If you don't understand the crypto in SAML, you're probably better off using a commercial product (like products from Ping Identity [Note:I do work for Ping]) to 1) speed up your deployment and more importantly 2) ensure that you are **secure and compliant**.